# Expand number range in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a series of number ranges that I need to expand. I have put these into a table broken into start, end and size of range (inclusive) with an associated range ID

For example:

```
Start       End         Size ID
01234567890 01234567892 3    001
01234567900 01234567999 100  002
etc
```

I would like to create a database that will allow these numbers to be expanded and apply the range ID to each in a new table
eg

```
Number      ID
01234567890 001
01234567891 001
01234567892 001
01234567900 002
01234567901 002
```

etc

This needs to be MS access as I will be providing it to other areas of the business. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnHC So what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of a numbers table. These are very easy to create and should contain integers from 0 to the highest number you will need, let us say 1000. Then you can say:

```
SELECT [Start]+[Number] AS Expanded, tbx.Size, tbx.ID
INTO Expanded
FROM Numbers, tbx
WHERE Numbers.Number<=[End]-[Start]
```

tbx is your existing table, Numbers is the numbers table and Expanded is the table being created.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with a query; you need VBA for it.

Basically, your function could look like this (pseudo-code):

```
Open a recordset of your first table
Loop through the records:
    For i = 0 to Size - 1:
        Insert into second table (Number + i, ID)
Close recordset
```